# How to display file names row-wise in web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I read files from Blob named 'pdf' and display in on the asp.net web form. Every file is read displayed in the ListView control. Each file is displayed one after another (side by side), instead of in a new line.

Each file is displayed by name with its hyperlink.

```
{
    pdfDisplayControl.DataSource = from o in 
     getfileGalleryContainer().GetDirectoryReference("pdf").ListBlobs()
                                       select new { Url = o.Uri };
    pdfDisplayControl.DataBind();

    }
```

........................................

```
{
<asp:ListView ID="pdfDisplayControl" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
 <asp:Hyperlink ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Hyperlink ID="pdfhyperlink" Text ='<%# 
  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("Url").ToString()) %>' runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' /> 
  </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
  }
```

All files are displayed as follows:

> file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf.

But I want to display as follows:

> file1.pdf.
>   file2.pdf
>   file3.pdf.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a css style of `display:block` to your hyperlink:

```
 <asp:Hyperlink style="display:block" ID="pdfhyperlink" Text ='<%# 
  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("Url").ToString()) %>' runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
```